# How can I use dependancies in a pimple DIC which need constructor arguments in Slim 3?

Tags: php, oop, slim, pimple

This questions is probably best explained with some code snippets. First I create the factory method in the pimple container to create or return the Blah object:

```
$container['blah'] = $container->factory(function ($c) {
  return new Blah();
});
```

Then later in my controlling code:

```
    $blah = $this->container->get('blah');
```

However, Blah has the following constructor:

```
public function __construct($some, $constructor, $arguments) {
  // .. etc
}
```

Is there a way I can pass in these arguments when getting Blah from the container? Many PHP classes have constructor arguments that are only really relevant at 'run time', rather than when bootstrapping your application.

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, or I'm doing it totally wrong..

Comment: Either instantiate using container params `new Blah($c->get('some'), $c->get('thing'))` or write setter for that params `$blah->setSome('some')->setThing('thing')`

Comment: When you define something in the container, you are basically deferring it's creation. Meaning that it is NOT created until you access it for the first time.